# Which culture used no personal names?

Tags: cultural-history, names

The blog post [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names – With Examples](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/) claims that:

> There was an isolated culture in which
>   no one had names – they referred to everyone in relative terms, such
>   as “my mother’s eldest sister”.

Is this true? Which culture is the author talking about?

Comment: Hello, I don't know but maybe this question has a biggest chance of having a conclusive answer in Skeptiks SE.

Comment: @Bregalad Erm, why? History.SE is equally good, if not better, at answering questions.

Comment: I remember in "Spirit Lake" by Mackinley Kantor (author of Pulitzer Prize-winning "Andersonville"), it was mentioned that among the Sioux characters, it was considered impolite to refer to someone by name; they used, e.g., "that one". Both books seem extremely well-researched. A brief search yielded something along these lines at https://www.warpaths2peacepipes.com/native-american-indian-names/

Comment: Weren't there native americans who only received names fairly late, and had no names while they were toddlers or small children?

Comment: @vsz Not only there — someone from Cameroon told me that traditionally, babies in her culture aren't given names before their 1st birthday, and sometimes only some years later.

Comment: Not a culture per se, but in general, Prison system uses numbering system instead of personal names.

Comment: @gerrit : this seems to be common for times where child mortality was very high. Why it wasn't common practice in Europe might be because of baptism being so tightly coupled with giving a name. And they wanted to baptize the child as soon as possible exactly because of high child mortality.

Comment: @Vishwa Where in the world is that (still) common practice?  "Of course every individual is unique.  That's why they all have their own unique number."

Comment: The Late Roman Republic and Early Empire did not give personal names to women.  They would be known by the female form of their father's nomen (family name), along with an ordinal number (first, second, etc.) akfir eldest daughter, second-oldest, etc.  If further clarity were necessary, you could add "daughter of" followed by the father's given name.

Comment: In India babies aren't given a name right away. It is common for birth certificates to not have names.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This would seem to be a piece of folklore.

> **Anthropologists have not found a single society which does not use
>   personal names in some form**; they are a human universal. However, the
>   forms that these names take and the ways in which they are bestowed
>   and used vary between cultures.

*Source: Abstract from Ellen S. Bramwell, '[Personal Names and Anthropology](https://www.oxfordhandbooks.com/view/10.1093/oxfordhb/9780199656431.001.0001/oxfordhb-9780199656431-e-29)'. In Carole Hough (ed.), 'The Oxford Handbook of Names and Naming' (2016)*

[William Bright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Bright) ([1928-2006](https://www.jstor.org/stable/4169584?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)), formerly a linguist at the [University of California](https://linguistics.ucla.edu/about/history/attachment/bright-photo-stanford/) and then  at the [University of Colorado](https://www.colorado.edu/program/clasp/william-bright), also covered this in a 2003 article *[What IS a Name? Reflections on Onomastics](http://www.ling.sinica.edu.tw/files/publication/j2003_4_01_3698.pdf)*:

> **There is a piece of folklore current among anthropologists regarding
>   the question of whether personal names exist in all societies. So far
>   I have not been able to trace this to a printed source**, but it is
>   somewhat as follows: Somewhere in the world there is a society where
>   people live in very small, isolated communities. In such a community,
>   people have no personal names; i.e., individuals have no name which
>   other people use to refer specifically to them. Instead, they are
>   referred to by descriptive expressions, e.g., ‘the blacksmith’ or ‘the
>   man who lives by the stream’. A woman will be referred to as, e.g.,
>   ‘the blacksmith’s wife’. Children will be referred to by expressions
>   such as ‘the blacksmith’s elder daughter’; when this daughter gets
>   married, she may be referred to as, e.g., ‘the wife of the man who
>   lives by the stream’.

He concludes that no such society exists, that

> any anthropologist who might have reported such a community was misled
>   by the operation of taboos on uttering personal names. I suggest, in
>   fact, that the use of personal names, having varying levels of
>   descriptiveness, is a sociolinguistic universal of the human species.

Bright points out that

> in non-literate societies, where names remain unwritten, there is
>   greater variety in naming customs (cf. the anthropological studies in
>   [Tooker 1984](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Naming_Systems.html?id=x8YNAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y)). A child may be given a “real” name at birth, but this
>   may be kept a secret throughout life. Elsewhere, such a “real” name
>   may be publicly known, but not used for everyday purposes; most of the
>   time, a nickname—perhaps descriptive, e.g., Shorty—may be used. A
>   person may be called by different names at different periods of life,
>   or by different people under changing conditions. Use of certain names
>   under particular circumstances may be forbidden by religious taboo; or
>   then again, such names may be replaced by descriptive nicknames.
>   Because of these factors, it may be difficult for the outside
>   investigator of such a society to determine what a person’s “real”
>   name is, or even what name is commonly used in the community; taboos
>   are likely to be especially strict when one is talking to outsiders.

An [Australian Institute of Family Studies](https://aifs.gov.au/) (AIFS) article *[Aboriginal families in Australia](https://aifs.gov.au/publications/archived/3539)* (1995) by Professor [Colin Bourke](https://www.uqp.uq.edu.au/Author.aspx/1012/Bourke,%20Colin) and Eleanor Bourke illustrates how confusing the issue of names can be:

> In many Aboriginal societies personal names were rarely used. People
>   were addressed by kinship terms. Some were referred to as being
>   someone else's son or daughter. In such societies personal names were
>   seen as being part of that person and were used with discretion. This
>   was often manifested by a deceased person's personal name being
>   removed from that language for some considerable time. Most languages
>   had a word meaning 'no name' which was used to refer to those persons
>   who had the same name as a recently deceased person.

Also, Wulf Schieffenhövel's article *[Reactions to cultural change](https://journals.openedition.org/civilisations/1632)* (1997) in the journal *[Civilisations](https://www.cairn-int.info/journal-civilisations.htm)* relates the problems the author encountered with the [Eipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eipo_language) in the Highlands of West-New Guinea:

> Each of them also seemed to answer my question: «An si?», what's
>   your name? It was only later when I had mastered the first steps into
>   this highly structured language, that I realized what these names
>   meant: Na-si-gumnye, Na-si-walwal, Na-si-urang, «I-the-one-who-has-no-name», «My-name-I-don't-know', «I-am-somebody-else». To give away one's *dibe si*, the «real name»,
>   exposes oneself to possible harm.

[Other studies](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/language-in-society/article/elizabeth-tooker-ed-harold-c-conklin-symposium-organizer-naming-systems-1980-proceedings-of-the-american-ethnological-society-washington-dc-the-american-ethnological-society-1984-pp-vii-107/E4A8A84B96D5E5394C03923EC63D42DF) from other regions of the world also show the importance and sometimes confusing (to outsiders) use of names: the [Ilongot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ilongot) in the Philippines (where people "acquire and lose" names during their lifetime), the [Kadayan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kedayan) in Brunei and Malaysia, societies in Central Brazil, and the [Mohawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohawk_people) people. These studies illustrate the "[diversity of the processes involved in naming and using names](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/language-in-society/article/elizabeth-tooker-ed-harold-c-conklin-symposium-organizer-naming-systems-1980-proceedings-of-the-american-ethnological-society-washington-dc-the-american-ethnological-society-1984-pp-vii-107/E4A8A84B96D5E5394C03923EC63D42DF)".

Stephen Wilson, in *[The Means of Naming: A Social and Cultural History of Personal Naming in Western Europe](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Means_of_Naming.html?id=VWBmAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)* (UCL Press, 1998), outlines just how important names have always been in societies, even though (as he notes elsewhere) historical documents have often not recorded them.

> In all societies...and more so in complex ones, a single individual is
>   known by a variety of names depending on the role he or she is playing
>   and the milieu of reference. So there will be one name used by close
>   relatives of origin, another by spouses and lovers, another by
>   children, another by friends, another in public, another at work, and
>   so on. Again, names here serve as a kind of social map, placing
>   individuals in the broader multi-dimensional landscape.

Wilson's primary area of study was Western Europe, but he also cites Gregory Bateson's work, [*Naven*](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=OEk7AAAAIAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1936), on the [Iatmul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iatmul_people) of New Guinea to show how important names are to both individuals and societies:

> Every spell, every song…contains lists of names. The utterances of
>   shamans are couched in terms of names… Marriages are often arranged in
>   order to gain names. Reincarnation and succession are based upon the
>   naming system. Land tenure is based on clan membership and clan
>   membership is vouched for by names.

To summarize, all societies use personal names, but

> Names are given to people at different stages of life; they change or
>   remain constant; they contain different elements; they connect with
>   relatives or tribes or they do not; they are used freely or they are
>   kept secret.

*Source: Ellen S. Bramwell, '[Personal Names and Anthropology](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=W2FQCwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)'. In Carole Hough (ed), 'The Oxford Handbook of Names and Naming' (2016)*

---

***(All emphasis is mine)***

Comment: (Note that from a programmer's perspective, a society with a strong taboo on giving their names to outsiders is just as much of a problem as a society that doesn't have names.)

Comment: @user3757614 Nah, they just need a taboo device in addition to a regular device. That way they can enter their PII securely.

Comment: In many societies, from ancient Rome to Victorian Britain, naming **women** in certain situations was considered impolite. Even into the 20th century, if a woman was the other party in divorce proceedings, she was **not** the "co-respondent", as a man was, but "the woman named" (in the petition) - the action title would be *Smith v Smith and The Woman Named *.

Comment: According to the elders running my niece's naming ceremony, Osages didn't actually give first-born daughters names, aside from a specific name meaning "first-born daughter". Presumably that was just official names though. When talking amongst themselves, one imagines the women *had* to have names they used. I'm pretty sure I've seen women's names in La Flesche's dictionary.

Comment: @TheHonRose: if by "certain situations" you mean "divorce cases or other potentially libellous allegations", that's hardly representative of the culture in general. The fact that the UK has the most punitive libel laws on the planet probably has more to do with it than culture. Witness the [farce of the 2011 super-injunction granted to footballer Ryan Giggs to prevent reporting on both his identity and his affair with Imogen Thomas](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/trials/celebrities-who-gave-up-super-7707541)

Comment: ...and the similarly absurd 2016 super-injunction against naming PJS and YMA (Elton John and his husband David Furnish, and Furnish's alleged long-time lover Daniel Laurence).

Comment: @user3757614, using names as identifiers for people is inherently difficult and flawed anyway. If your data set is large enough even combinations of name, DoB, birth place will stop being unique: you'll need to either create or rely on some sort of unique identifier (often this ends up being a social security number or equivalent, which of course has it's own array of issues).

Comment: @smci No, I did not simply mean divorce cases, and the argument re libel did not stop male parties being named. But "bandying" a lady's name was considered very bad form in, for instance, a gentlemen's club/army mess. When the London Foundling Hospital was set up, many of the primary supporters were Society ladies, but **none** are named on the list of subscribers - their husbands are!

Answer (score 3):

I know its been a while, but it's a tribe in the Amazon, the [Matsigenka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machiguenga#Culture).

Comment: HAve you got any source to link to back up this claim ?